# How To Prefill A Text-Area Based On A Link From Another HTML Page

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, datatable, autofill

I'm working on a website right now where one page is just a single column of div's that have links which go to another page on the site. This other page has textareas used to filter data (It's a table that implements "DataTables"). I want to pre-fill one of these text areas with the text of the div/link that redirects user from the first page to the second (i.e. if on page #1 a user were to click "carnivals," the textareas on the second page would be prefilled with "carnivals" in order to filter the datatable for related entries). Any idea how I could accomplish something like this using HTML?

Comment: Simply try redirecting the page with query string. And in the next page (i.e., redirected one) just use the Query string value and do necessary bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Let me think your page is having a link "carnivals".

Let us consider in First page You are having the following link

```
<a href="/Carnivals.html?Key=Carnivals">Carnivals</a>
```

Here `?Key=Carnivals` is a Query String which is taking "Carnivals" value to the next page which is `MyCarnivalsPage.html`

Now use the following function to retrieve the value from the query string.

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Now fill your textarea with the resulted value

```
document.getElementById("YourID").value = getParameterByName("Key", window.location.href);
```